# How to add cells together if it is a certain month

Tags: excel-formula

In Excel, I have tabs set up for YTD and each month. I'm trying to add volumes and revenue for the year, but only when it's a certain month. So for July, I want the YTD tab to only sum July. For August, I want to sum together July and August, and etc. for the remainder of the year.

I've tried different "If Month=7, then...." formulas, but they either only count the specific month (only July) or they return an error when I try to add in 2 months (July and August).

My goal is that when I have the formulas set up, I won't need to manually adjust the YTD tab formulas to include the current months, but it will automatically update. So on July 31st, it will automatically sum up the July tab. But when it turns to August 1st, it will start automatically summing up the July and August tabs.

July 31st:
Volume = July Volume

August 1st:
Volume = July Volume + August Volume

[Excel Q Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ckWDjIVcGFQe0DJH41hF0vK9DwbZ23DKiX1nTXmYXZQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Without example data to look at, you could use sumifs()

Comment: I've added a google sheet with examples if that helps you guys

Comment: be aware that excel formulas and google sheet formulas while having the same name, do not always perform functions in the same way.  Only saying that because you said you posted a google sheet for an excel question.

Comment: base on the tag.. it is an excel question. | Dear jr92, Can we see the "I've tried different "If Month=7, then...." formulas, but they either only count the specific month (only July) " formula.. ?